# Find highest scoring pair of nodes in graph.

Tags: graph, nodes, graph-theory

I'm trying so solve an optimization problem where I want to find a combination of two nodes with the highest impact/importance in a graph. Lets say I want to base this on betweenness centrality (BC). I guess the more sensible approach is to select one node (maybe one with a high BC), then calculate the BC for the resulting network and then remove the node with the highest value for BC. My goal is to generate a list of the highest scoring combinations of nodes when removed from the original graph. I've implemented a simplified method that picks out random nodes and if the score is higher than the previous, one of the two nodes is reused in the next combination. I'm not sure if this approach is good enough of if the code will "get stuck" at local optima combinations.
Any pointers to steer me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: To be certain you have the highest pair, test them all.  Unless your data is very forgiving, this will likely show your algorithm getting stuck, as you suggest -- nature of the beast.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is with a large sized graph is that I then need to run a centrality algorithm N*(N-1) times because its something like N*(N-1)/2 unique combinations and maybe I need to run it twice per combination. So I was kind of hoping the was an optimization alternative where only a fraction of these combinations are calculated.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there are properties of the graph and/or function that you can exploit, you have to check all pairs to be sure that the maximum is found.

Answer (score 0):

Several approximate betweenness centrality calculation algorithms have been proposed.

Your general method is good, and it is somewhat similar to the one used in *Fast approximation of betweenness centrality through sampling* [Riondato, Kornaropoulos] 2015. [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10618-015-0423-0) [here](http://matteo.rionda.to/papers/RiondatoKornaropoulos-BetweennessSampling-DMKD.pdf).

Quoting:

> "Since exact computation in large networks is prohibitively expensive,
>   we present two efficient randomized algorithms for betweenness
>   estimation. The algorithms are based on random sampling of shortest
>   paths and offer probabilistic guarantees on the quality of the
>   approximation. [...] The first algorithm estimates the betweenness of all vertices (or edges): all approximate values are within an additive factor ε ∈ (0, 1) from the real values, with probability at least 1 − δ. The second algorithm focuses on the top-K vertices (or edges) with highest betweenness and estimate their betweenness value to within a multiplicative factor ε, with probability at least 1 − δ. This is the first algorithm that can compute such approximation for the top-K vertices (or edges). "

The time complexity for both algorithms is O(r*(|E|+|V| log |V|)), where r is the sample size (which determines the accuracy).

Their second algorithm is quite relevant for your use case (K=2):

> "This is the first algorithm that can compute such approximation for
>   the top-K vertices (or edges)."

Answer (score 0):

First, calculate betweeness centrality value for all nodes. Sort in ascending order. Select the node with the highest BC value and remove it from the network. Reconnect the remaining nodes and repeat the process continuously. This will enable you pick the nodes with the highest BC on the network.